# Adding multiple inference on TensorRT (Invalid Resource Handle Error)

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycuda, tensorrt, nvidia-jetson

I am trying to run two inferences in a pipeline using Jetson Nano. The first inference is object detection using MobileNet and TensorRT. My code for the first inference is pretty much replicated from the [AastaNV/TRT_Obj_Detection](https://github.com/AastaNV/TRT_object_detection) repository. The only difference being that I changed that code so that it resides inside a class Inference1.

The second inference job uses the outputs of the first inference to run further analysis. For this inference, I use tensorflow (not TensorRT, but I assume it is called in the backend?) using a custom model. This model is loaded from a `.pb` file (frozen graph). Once loaded, the inference is performed by calling the `session.run()` command of tensorflow.

If I run ONLY Inference1 or ONLY Inference2, the code runs properly without any errors. However, when I pipe them, I get the error `[TensorRT] ERROR: cuda/caskConvolutionLayer.cpp (355) - Cuda Error in execute: 33 (invalid resource handle)`

From what I see in the log, the TensorRT serialized graph is loaded without any problems. Tensorflow is also imported and it recognizes my GPU. From my searching on the internet I have found that this problem maybe related to CUDA Contexts? I therefore show below how i have setup the CUDA context in my code below. The `create_cuda_context` is only called once during the initialization of the Inference1 class. The `run_inference_for_single_image` is called every iteration.

Code:

```py
def create_cuda_context(self):
    self.host_inputs, self.host_outputs = [], []
    self.cuda_inputs, self.cuda_outputs = [], []
    self.bindings = []
    self.stream = cuda.Stream()

    for binding in self.engine:
        size = trt.volume(self.engine.get_binding_shape(binding)) * self.engine.max_batch_size
        host_mem = cuda.pagelocked_empty(size, np.float32)
        cuda_mem = cuda.mem_alloc(host_mem.nbytes)

        self.bindings.append(int(cuda_mem))
        if self.engine.binding_is_input(binding):
            self.host_inputs.append(host_mem)
            self.cuda_inputs.append(cuda_mem)
        else:
            self.host_outputs.append(host_mem)
            self.cuda_outputs.append(cuda_mem)
    self.context = self.engine.create_execution_context()

def run_inference_for_single_image(self, image):
    ''' Copies the image (already raveled) input into GPU memory, performs the forward pass
    and copies the result back to CPU memory
    '''
    np.copyto(self.host_inputs[0], image)
    cuda.memcpy_htod_async(self.cuda_inputs[0], self.host_inputs[0], self.stream)
    self.context.execute_async(bindings=self.bindings, stream_handle=self.stream.handle)
    cuda.memcpy_dtoh_async(self.host_outputs[1], self.cuda_outputs[1], self.stream)
    cuda.memcpy_dtoh_async(self.host_outputs[0], self.cuda_outputs[0], self.stream)
    self.stream.synchronize()
    return self.host_outputs[0]
```

Log:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/graphsurgeon/DynamicGraph.py:4: The name tf.GraphDef is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.GraphDef instead.

[TensorRT] INFO: Glob Size is 14049908 bytes.
[TensorRT] INFO: Added linear block of size 5760000
[TensorRT] INFO: Added linear block of size 2880000
[TensorRT] INFO: Added linear block of size 409600
[TensorRT] INFO: Added linear block of size 218624
[TensorRT] INFO: Added linear block of size 61440
[TensorRT] INFO: Added linear block of size 57344
[TensorRT] INFO: Added linear block of size 30720
[TensorRT] INFO: Added linear block of size 20992
[TensorRT] INFO: Added linear block of size 9728
[TensorRT] INFO: Added linear block of size 9216
[TensorRT] INFO: Added linear block of size 2560
[TensorRT] INFO: Added linear block of size 2560
[TensorRT] INFO: Added linear block of size 1024
[TensorRT] INFO: Added linear block of size 512
[TensorRT] INFO: Found Creator FlattenConcat_TRT
[TensorRT] INFO: Found Creator GridAnchor_TRT
[TensorRT] INFO: Found Creator FlattenConcat_TRT
[TensorRT] INFO: Found Creator NMS_TRT
[TensorRT] INFO: Deserialize required 5159079 microseconds.
Infering on input.mp4
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/user/Desktop/SVM_TensorRT/deep_sort/tools/generate_detections.py:75: The name tf.Session is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.Session instead.

2018-01-29 02:01:38.254282: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2018-01-29 02:01:38.286962: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:972] ARM64 does not support NUMA - returning NUMA node zero
2018-01-29 02:01:38.287300: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1640] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: NVIDIA Tegra X1 major: 5 minor: 3 memoryClockRate(GHz): 0.9216
pciBusID: 0000:00:00.0
2018-01-29 02:01:38.287552: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.0
2018-01-29 02:01:38.287744: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10.0
2018-01-29 02:01:38.287983: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10.0
2018-01-29 02:01:38.288201: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10.0
2018-01-29 02:01:38.415478: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10.0
2018-01-29 02:01:38.484010: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10.0
2018-01-29 02:01:38.484668: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2018-01-29 02:01:38.485343: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:972] ARM64 does not support NUMA - returning NUMA node zero
2018-01-29 02:01:38.486009: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:972] ARM64 does not support NUMA - returning NUMA node zero
2018-01-29 02:01:38.486286: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1763] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-01-29 02:01:38.665379: W tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:98] Failed to find bogomips in /proc/cpuinfo; cannot determine CPU frequency
2018-01-29 02:01:38.682935: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x24f9ea50 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
2018-01-29 02:01:38.683009: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (0): <undefined>, <undefined>
2018-01-29 02:01:38.764975: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:972] ARM64 does not support NUMA - returning NUMA node zero
2018-01-29 02:01:38.765291: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x572614c0 executing computations on platform CUDA. Devices:
2018-01-29 02:01:38.765349: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (0): NVIDIA Tegra X1, Compute Capability 5.3
2018-01-29 02:01:38.766014: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:972] ARM64 does not support NUMA - returning NUMA node zero
2018-01-29 02:01:38.766158: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1640] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: NVIDIA Tegra X1 major: 5 minor: 3 memoryClockRate(GHz): 0.9216
pciBusID: 0000:00:00.0
2018-01-29 02:01:38.766716: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.0
2018-01-29 02:01:38.766814: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10.0
2018-01-29 02:01:38.766879: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10.0
2018-01-29 02:01:38.767002: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10.0
2018-01-29 02:01:38.767174: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10.0
2018-01-29 02:01:38.767311: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10.0
2018-01-29 02:01:38.767423: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2018-01-29 02:01:38.767731: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:972] ARM64 does not support NUMA - returning NUMA node zero
2018-01-29 02:01:38.768049: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:972] ARM64 does not support NUMA - returning NUMA node zero
2018-01-29 02:01:38.768136: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1763] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-01-29 02:01:38.783718: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.0
2018-01-29 02:01:41.046094: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1181] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018-01-29 02:01:41.046260: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1187]      0 
2018-01-29 02:01:41.046311: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1200] 0:   N 
2018-01-29 02:01:41.054160: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:972] ARM64 does not support NUMA - returning NUMA node zero
2018-01-29 02:01:41.054730: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:972] ARM64 does not support NUMA - returning NUMA node zero
2018-01-29 02:01:41.112041: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1326] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 85 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: NVIDIA Tegra X1, pci bus id: 0000:00:00.0, compute capability: 5.3)
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/user/Desktop/SVM_TensorRT/deep_sort/tools/generate_detections.py:76: The name tf.gfile.GFile is deprecated. Please use tf.io.gfile.GFile instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/user/Desktop/SVM_TensorRT/deep_sort/tools/generate_detections.py:80: The name tf.get_default_graph is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph instead.

[TensorRT] ERROR: CUDA cask failure at execution for trt_maxwell_scudnn_128x32_relu_small_nn_v1.
[TensorRT] ERROR: cuda/caskConvolutionLayer.cpp (355) - Cuda Error in execute: 33 (invalid resource handle)
[TensorRT] ERROR: cuda/caskConvolutionLayer.cpp (355) - Cuda Error in execute: 33 (invalid resource handle)
```

Answer (score 5):

I believe the two models you are trying to run both try to create CUDA Context. The first one initialize CUDA Context directly from TensorRT library, while the 2nd one initize new CUDA Context inside Tensorflow. When the 1st model tries to perform inferencing, it will use wrong CUDA Context, resulting with that error.

If you are using the same TensorRT, Tensorflow (or other CUDA Libraries) for both models, it will be a lot easier to control CUDA Context. From my experience, Tensorflow and direct CUDA are not playing along well.

I would suggest that you separate both models into different thread. That will ensure that both TensorRT and Tensorflow create and use their own different CUDA Contexts... (given that you are not running to OOM problem. I once tried to use both SSD+MobileNetV2 for object detection and another MobileNet for more classification on detected object on Jetson Nano. I faced the OOM and ended up running the 2nd model on CPU instead).

Comment: Hi, I facing same issue even both of them are tensorrt models. my error was: `Error Code 1: Cuda Runtime (invalid resource handle)`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error and that is what helped me in this case:

1. Remove `import pycuda.autoinit` and do

   ```
   import pycuda.driver as cuda
   ...
   cuda.init()
   device = cuda.Device(0)
   cuda_driver_context = device.make_context()
   ```
2. Wrap the piece of code that does inference with TensorRT like this:

   ```
   cuda_driver_context.push()
   # copy data to device memory, run inference, copy data from device memory
   cuda_driver_context.pop()
   ```

See [the related thread on NVidia's forum](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/how-to-use-tensorrt-by-the-multi-threading-package-of-python/123085/8).

Comment: you have saved my day, thank you very much